# Runtime.exec() method always returns empty in Spring environment

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, java-8, apache-commons

I tried to execute `Runtime.exec(…)` method in my Spring application and then always getting empty result from `getInputStream()` method. But it's working well if I execute as a core java application. Is any other implementations needed to execute in Spring environment? Thanks in advance.

- Spring Version     : 4.2.1.RELEASE
- commons-io Version : 2.4

  ```
  try {
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"sh", "-c", "spamc < abcd.txt"});
      String spamResponsexx = IOUtils.toString(p.getInputStream());
      log.debug("Spam Response : " + spamResponsexx);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      log.error("", e);
  }
  ```

Comment: You should also be looking at the error stream (`p.getErrorStream()`) there may well be a message on that stream.

Comment: It is unlikely that spring has anything to do with your perceived problem.

Comment: Maybe, the current directory is different, hence `abcd.txt` is not found (or a different file named `abcd.txt`)…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe User privileges issues. I'm also worked in the similar type of scenario.

1. In this case both services should be run as same user(XYZ)
2. Otherwise 'spamc' library files location should be point to your user(XYZ) HOME path '.bashrc' and reset '.bashrc'